# 16x2 lcd lighting up blue but not showing any text

Tags: lcd

i should probably start off by saying i am really new to this stuff and have barely any idea what i'm doing. i am triyng to use a DHT22 and a 16x2 LCD to show the temperature and humidity. here is the code i'm using:

```
#include <DHT.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

// initialize the library by associating any needed LCD interface pin
// with the arduino pin number it is connected to
const int rs = 12, en = 11, d4 = 5, d5 = 4, d6 = 3, d7 = 2;
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);

//Constants
#define DHTPIN 7     // what pin we're connected to
#define DHTTYPE DHT22   // DHT 22  (AM2302)
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE); //// Initialize DHT sensor for normal 16mhz Arduino


//Variables
int chk;
float hum;  //Stores humidity value
float temp; //Stores temperature value

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  dht.begin();
  lcd.begin(16,2);
}

void loop()
{

  delay(2000);
  //Read data and store it to variables hum and temp
  hum = dht.readHumidity();
  temp = dht.readTemperature();
  //Print temp and humidity values to serial monitor
  Serial.print("Humidity: ");
  Serial.print(hum);
  Serial.print(" %, Temp: ");
  Serial.print(temp);
  Serial.println(" Celsius");

  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Temp: ");
  lcd.print(temp);
  lcd.print(" ");
  lcd.print((char)223);
  lcd.print("C");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Hum:  ");
  lcd.print(hum);
  lcd.print(" %");

  delay(2000); //Delay 2 sec.

}`
```

is it an issue with my code or my hardware? thanks

Comment: start by running an LCD example sketch with only the LCD connected

Comment: You must use D0-D3 as data lines as you are using 8-bit LCD in 4-bit format

Comment: You need to set the correct contrast on these displays. Try turning the potentiometer (connected to pin 3 / VE)  till you see text/blocks appear.

Comment: You haven't told us what did you obtained? Anything on LCD? Can you make a clear photo of your hardware setup?